# How to put imageView in full dimensions?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am working on app for android in eclipse and testing on my Samuns Galaxy Tab 2.0 7 (600x1024). I have problem when I put imageView (image is 600x300) because image is not filled  up whole screen, there is padding:

[image]

HOw to remove that padding and put image on whole screen?

This is xml of imageView:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:baselineAlignBottom="true"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    android:src="@drawable/bg_large" />
```

I have wrote but I will again because there are consusions, I want to set image in full dimensions (600x300) on that screen which is 600x1024. On ss you can see that image is not in full width (cca. 580) and I can't put to the top, there is also padding.

Comment: I have post solution down in another post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

I have create empty android project and by default eclipse put me in activity_main.xml this code:

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

now when I have removed this I can put my image in full dimensions.

I hope this will help someone.

Comment: @Stacks28 - yes but now I see that is not still in natural dimensions, is there some setup that I can set that image must be in natural dimensions. If image is 600x300 that there is in screen 600x300, not 600x400 and etc.?

Comment: I think about imageView